# Using Prepare and Execute

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor, into-outfile

I have a table that has training records. Each record has a field with an Agency value. I have another table of just agency values. I want to export the records into CSV files for each agency. There are over 2 million records so I don't want to export the whole table and do it manually.

I've created a stored procedure that pulls a value from the agency_codes table using a cursor and uses that value in a select statement for the **WHERE** clause and part of the **INTO OUTFILE** name.

The procedure works but only for the first two values in the agency_codes table. On the third (ACB) value it gives the error **Unknown column 'ACB' in 'where clause'** I'm confused why it worked with the first two values then stops with the third.

Here is the procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  export_csv $$
CREATE PROCEDURE export_csv()
BEGIN
DECLARE agency_name VARCHAR(255);

DECLARE exit_loop BOOLEAN;         

DECLARE agency_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT agency FROM agency_codes;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;

OPEN agency_cursor;

agency_loop: LOOP
FETCH  agency_cursor INTO agency_name;

SET @sql_text = Concat("(select 'class_code','course_code','course_name','course_type','username','grade_type','score','letter_grade','is_passed','completion_date','completion_status','registration_date','registration_entry_status','registration_type','comment','first_name','last_name','class_name','agency') Union (select class_code,course_code,course_name,course_type,username,grade_type,score,letter_grade,is_passed,completion_date,completion_status,registration_date,registration_entry_status,registration_type,comment,first_name,last_name,class_name,agency from hrdis_oru where hrdis_oru.agency =", agency_name," into outfile 'C:/HDD/",agency_name,".csv' fields enclosed by '\"' terminated by ',' escaped by '\"' lines terminated by '\r\n')");

prepare s1 from @sql_text;
execute s1;
deallocate prepare s1; 


IF exit_loop THEN
     CLOSE agency_cursor;
     LEAVE agency_loop;
 END IF;
END LOOP agency_loop;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The first few values in my Agency table are:

- 17
- 303
- ACB
- Actuary
- agr
- AIM

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about what values `@sql_text` will hold on each iteration, the problem should be immediately obvious.  Adding some whitespace for clarity:

```
(
  select 'class_code','course_code','course_name','course_type','username',
         'grade_type','score','letter_grade','is_passed','completion_date',
         'completion_status','registration_date','registration_entry_status',
         'registration_type','comment','first_name','last_name','class_name',
         'agency'
) Union (
  select class_code,course_code,course_name,course_type,username,
         grade_type,score,letter_grade,is_passed,completion_date,
         completion_status,registration_date,registration_entry_status,
         registration_type,comment,first_name,last_name,class_name,
         agency
  from   hrdis_oru
  where  hrdis_oru.agency =ACB
  into   outfile 'C:/HDD/ACB.csv'
  fields enclosed   by '\"'
         terminated by ','
         escaped    by '\"'
  lines  terminated by '\r\n'
)
```

Note in particular, `where htdis_oru.agency =ACB`.

Since `ACB` has not been quoted, MySQL parses it as a schema object identifier and complains when it cannot find any such-named object (this isn't the case with the purely numeric agency names, since they are parsed as integers that subsequently get [cast to strings during expression evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/type-conversion.html)).

For MySQL to correctly parse non-numeric values as string literals, they must be quoted:

```
... where hrdis_oru.agency ='", agency_name, "' ...
                            ^                 ^
```

Naturally, this presents a problem should `agency_name` contain the `'` string quotation character—any such occurrences must of course be [escaped](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).  MySQL handily provides a [`QUOTE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) function for precisely this purpose:

```
... where hrdis_oru.agency =", QUOTE(agency_name), " ...
```

However, to guard against possible SQL injection attacks, you really should instead *parameterise* your prepared statement:

```
FETCH agency_cursor INTO @agency_name;
```

(You no longer need to `DECLARE agency_name`); then:

```
... where hrdis_oru.agency = ? into outfile CONCAT('C:/HDD/', ?, '.csv') ...
```

Followed by:

```
PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE s1 USING @agency_name, @agency_name;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
```

Note that you can now also `PREPARE` the statement *before* entering the loop and simply `EXECUTE` it (with appropriate values) inside the loop—this should yield a slight performance improvement.  Remember to `DEALLOCATE` after exiting the loop.

One final note: you should inspect `exit_loop` *immediately* after the `FETCH` command—otherwise you will end up attempting to execute the `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` statement a final time when there are no more agencies.

---

It may also be worth noting that, in this case, you have no particular need to use prepared statements at all.  You could simply do the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE export_csv() BEGIN
  DECLARE agency_name VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE agency_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT agency FROM agency_codes;
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND CLOSE agency_cursor;

  OPEN agency_cursor;
  LOOP
    FETCH agency_cursor INTO agency_name;

      SELECT 'class_code','course_code','course_name','course_type','username',
             'grade_type','score','letter_grade','is_passed','completion_date',
             'completion_status','registration_date','registration_entry_status',
             'registration_type','comment','first_name','last_name','class_name'

    UNION ALL

      SELECT class_code,course_code,course_name,course_type,username,
             grade_type,score,letter_grade,is_passed,completion_date,
             completion_status,registration_date,registration_entry_status,
             registration_type,comment,first_name,last_name,class_name
      FROM   hrdis_oru
      WHERE  agency = agency_name

    INTO   OUTFILE CONCAT('C:/HDD/', agency_name, '.csv')
    FIELDS ENCLOSED   BY '"'
           TERMINATED BY ','
           ESCAPED    BY '"'
    LINES  TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

  END LOOP;
END
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly and saved me hours of work. I'll try out not using the prepared statements.